# Xpath Find Last Non-None Element

Tags: xpath

I have an Xml which goes like

```
<Node1>
<Node2 name = "A" >
  <Node3>
    <ChildNode>blah blah</ChildNode>
  </Node3>
</Node2>    
<Node2 name = "B" >
  <Node3>
    <ChildNode></ChildNode>
  </Node3>
</Node2>
</Node1>
```

My requirement is to find the last node which is "Not None" here..

I tried '/Node1/Node2[ last() ]//Node3ChildNode/text( )' but here the last node is empty so want to default to the previous node. 
What would be the best way to do that via Xpath ?

Answer (score 0):

Select the last  Node 3 with not empty ChildNode

```
(/Node1/Node2[Node3/ChildNode/text()])[last()]/Node3/ChildNode/text()
```

Or select the last one from all not empty ChildNode

```
(/Node1/Node2/Node3/ChildNode/text())[last()]
```

Comment: Tx a lot @splash58 for the swift response. That does it !!.